# Laravel repository model executing two queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement a criteria model based on this [package](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

If I am pushing the following criteria which does a join and fetches the required coloumns, its suppose to execute a single query. But its executing two queries

```
select `products`.`product_name`, `skus`.`quantity` from `products` inner join `skus` on `skus`.`products_id` = `products`.`products_id` where `products`.`products_id` = '1'380μshomestead

select * from `products` where `products`.`products_id` = '0' limit 1
```

Why is it executing two queries where I only need to execute the first one?

Code samples as follows

### Controller

```
public function __construct(ProductRepository $product_repository){
        $this->product_repository = $product_repository;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $data = $this->product_repository->getByCriteria(new GetProduct());
        $product = $this->product_repository->find('1');

    }
```

### Criteria Repository

```
class getProduct implements CriteriaInterface {

    public function apply($model, RepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        $model = $model
                ->select('products.product_name', 'skus.quantity')
                ->where('products.products_id', '1')
                ->join('skus', 'skus.products_id', '=', 'products.products_id');
        return $model; 
    }
}
```

### dd($data) yielded the below

```
Collection {#300 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Product {#301 ▼
      #primaryKey: "products_id"
      #fillable: []
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:2 [▶]
      #original: array:2 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => Product {#302 ▼
      #primaryKey: "products_id"
      #fillable: []
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:2 [▶]
      #original: array:2 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a `dd($data)` right before the `$product` just to see what is being returned to the `$data` ??
It seems that que query with the criteria is being executed ok, however you are performing another query with `$this->product_repository->find('1');`

Comment: Got this ' FatalErrorException in ProductController.php line 24:
Can't use function return value in write context' error when I put the dd

Comment: Well it's executing two queries, because your are doing two queries, this is the fisrt query `$data = $this->product_repository->getByCriteria(new GetProduct());` and this is your second query `$product = $this->product_repository->find('1');` if you just want the first query remove the second line

Comment: well, this should not happen. You should be getting the query results from from that dd(). Did you declared the `$fieldSearchable` in your models? Also, if your plan is to add the criteria and then perfom the second query use `pushCriteria` instead of `getByCriteria`

Comment: @cbcaio Sorry the dd which I given had  a syntax error. This is what I got.Please check updated Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I guess we have a solution. You are executing 2 queries

One here:

```
$data = $this->product_repository->getByCriteria(new GetProduct());
```

relative to :

```
select `products`.`product_name`, `skus`.`quantity` from `products` inner join `skus` on `skus`.`products_id` = `products`.`products_id` where `products`.`products_id` = '1'
```

and another one here

```
$product = $this->product_repository->find('1');
```

relative to:

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`products_id` = '0' limit 1
```

If your plan was to use the criteria and then perform the query, change `getByCriteria` for `pushCriteria`, like this

```
$data = $this->product_repository->pushCriteria(new GetProduct());
```

Doing this you are telling your repository you want all the queries to follow what was specified in that criteria, so all your next queries will be using that criteria. So, when you do `$product = $this->product_repository->find('1');` you will be actually getting

```
->select('products.product_name', 'skus.quantity')
->where('products.products_id', '1')
->join('skus', 'skus.products_id', '=', 'products.products_id')
->find('1');
```

Hope I helped and its clear now why you are getting 2 queries from that code.

Comment: Im happy that helped :)

Comment: One more clarification I require from you. Can I pass the coloumns which I need from the controller? Any way to do that ?

Comment: What you mean? Aren't you doing that when you used  `->select('products.product_name', 'skus.quantity')` ?

Comment: but its been hardcoded in the criteria. What if i need to dynamically pass the coloumn names from the controller?

Comment: well... i just tought of a way, but maybe is not the right approach. In your GetProduct class, specify in the constructor an array of strings, something like 
`public function __construct($string){
$this->columns = $string;
}`
then change your criteria to add these strings as the columns in the select.
When you use your criteria in the controller just use `pushCriteria(new GetProduct(['column1', 'column2']));` , it might work